# How to draw outline around a PNG image using JAVA in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, bitmap, png, android-canvas

I have a PNG image (with transparent background) and I want to **draw an outline around its visible pixels only**. (See example GIF attached). I want to get this all done in `JAVA`.

I've read many Q&A over stackoverflow and around the web but I didn't find anything anyway near to my requirements.

**P.S:** We don't have to draw the same image twice on canvas and use the bottom one as outline, so please don't propose such solutions.

**P.P.S:** I would be great if this solution lets me draw an outline around all visible objects/elements (images & textviews etc) inside a canvas or inside a layout.[image: outline of a png image in Android Canvas]

Answer (score -1):

Try using Open CV and drawing contours. It is the closest available solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It would be better if you'd link some resources for beginners like me. As I don't know anything about Open CV and drawing contours.